# Microsoft multi factor authentication using angular redirect issue

Tags: angular, multi-factor-authentication

In my angular project, I am using Microsoft Authentication. The issue which I am facing is when I give insted popup to redirect, after authentication my page is refreshing many times. But for the popup case it is working fine.

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
        clientId: 'Enter_the_Application_Id_Here',
        authority: 'Enter_the_Cloud_Instance_Id_HereEnter_the_Tenant_Info_Here',
        redirectUri: 'Enter_the_Redirect_Uri_Here',
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
      },
    },
    {
      popUp: true,
      consentScopes: [
        'user.read',
        'openid',
        'profile',
      ],
      unprotectedResources: [],
      protectedResourceMap: [
        ['Enter_the_Graph_Endpoint_Herev1.0/me', ['user.read']]
      ],
      extraQueryParameters: {}
    })
  ],
```

If I give ***popUp: true*** it is working as expected. But if I give ***popUp: false*** and if I am not giving anything it is redirecting to login page but after login the page is getting refreshed many times

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the `IMsalService` as implemented in [the official example app](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular10-browser-sample), here is the official solution

```js
@Injectable()
export class MsalService implements IMsalService {
    private redirectHash: string;

    constructor(
        @Inject(MSAL_INSTANCE) private msalInstance: IPublicClientApplication,
        private location: Location
    ) {
        // Cache the code hash before Angular router clears it
        const hash = this.location.path(true).split('#').pop();
        if (hash) {
            this.redirectHash = `#${hash}`;
        }
    }
    ...
    handleRedirectObservable(): Observable<AuthenticationResult> {
        return from(this.msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise(this.redirectHash));
    }
    ...
}
```

This fix was merged by the following [PR](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/pull/2495)
The full discussion about the issue lives [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2268)

Briefly, angular is doing naviagation before `msal` can resolve it's auth promise.

In my old job i faced simillar issues, which led us to use `msal.js` instead `@azure/msal-angular`, so if you are using `@azure/msal-angular` and this fix  doesn't work for you, i would strongly recommend you to switch to `msal.js` and create your own angular-msal implementation.

**EDIT**

So by refering `msal.js` I mean `@azure/msal-browser` and this [Repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser#advanced-topics)
(look at the vanilla js implementations) so the thing that I'am suggesting is dedecating the time to write your own `msal` wrapper to fit your case.

Comment: I am using  "msal": "^1.3.0", and  "@azure/msal-angular": "^1.1.1", packages. So I did not understand what is this msal.js file and where I need to add this

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the above did not work for me... And below update in app.component.ts is what worked.
Maybe a late reply, but hopefully, it will be useful for others looking for the answer

```
    if(window.location.hash) {
  let resetPasswordFlowRequest = {
    scopes: ["openid"],
    authority: this.isFrench ? b2cPoliciesFr.authorities.forgotPassword.authority : b2cPolicies.authorities.forgotPassword.authority,
  };
  this.authService.handleRedirectObservable().subscribe({
    next: (result: AuthenticationResult) => {
      //
    },
    error: (error) => { 
      if (error.errorMessage.lastIndexOf("cancelled") > 0) this.authService.loginRedirect();
      else this.authService.loginRedirect(resetPasswordFlowRequest);
     }
  });
} else {
  this.login();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below method needs to be handles in order to ensure no refresh

```
msalInstance.handleRedirectObservable()
```